# MBProgressHUD display messages one over the other

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mbprogresshud

In the viewDidload method, i am using `MBProgressHUD` to show an activity indicator until data is downloaded from the net, and thereafter to check if the application has enabled GPS. based on this i alert the user using `MBProgressHUD`.

My code;

ViewDidLoad

```
hudForDownloadData = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view hudForDownloadData ];   
hudForDownloadData .delegate = self;
hudForDownloadData .labelText = @"Loading";
hudForDownloadData .detailsLabelText = @"updating data";
[hudForDownloadData showWhileExecuting:@selector(downloadDataFromWebService) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

[self downloadDataFromWebService]; // This method is called, and then data is downloaded from the webservice, once the data is downloaded i will remove the `MBProgressHUD ` alert
```

Now i am checking if the application has enabled access to GPS, and alert the user if not.

```
 hudForGPS = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
     [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];   
     hudForGPS .delegate = self;
     hudForGPS .labelText = @"Loading";
     hudForGPS .detailsLabelText = @"updating data";
     [hudForGPS showWhileExecuting:@selector(checkIfApplicationEnabledGPS)
onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES]; // This will only take a
 maximum of 2-3 seconds. and i will remove it after that
```

The problem is that; when the internet/wifi is down, the `hudForDownloadData` will continuously animate (display uiactivityindicator). In the meantime `hudForGPS` will also execute. But it will display below `hudForDownloadData` . So the user will not be able to see it.

What i want to do is to execute the `checkIfApplicationEnabledGPS` first, and wait till its alert finishes (it will only take 2-3 seconds), and then load execute the `downloadDataFromWebService` where if the internet/wifi is not available it will display forever.

How can i do this programatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Execute checkIfApplicationEnabledGPS first and when it is finished,you show an alert box,If you are using UiAlertView to show the alert then you can handle it's delegate:-

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

when the user presses ok button in UiAlert view you can override the above delegate with hudForDownloadData

In this way both the checkIfApplicationEnabledGPS and hudForDownloadData will be executed one after the other

Comment: I need to use Customized alerts in both instances (MBProgressHUD )

Comment: In that case also there would be no problem,you could create your own alertview and can handle its own  button's IBactions

Comment: hudWasHidden ,Are u using this delegate of MBProgressHUD when checkIfApplicationEnabledGPS is finished ?